# Start specific service only with docker compose up scale

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  service1:
    image: image1
  service2:
    image: image2
  service3:
    image: image3
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

The `replicas: 0` ensures the service only starts on demand: I don't want to it to start automatically.

Assuming that compose project isn't running; I want to start `service3` only:

```
docker compose up -d --scale service3=1
```

That starts `service3`, but also `service1` and `service2`.

How can I start `service3` only?

Note:

- docker swarm is not an option in this case
- docker profiles are not an option in this case (it has some [issues](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8139))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only start one service when using `docker compose up`, you have to specify the said service as an argument of your command, as shown in the help of the command:

> $ docker compose up --help
>
> Usage:  docker compose up [OPTIONS] **[SERVICE...]**

So, in your case you have to do:

```bash
docker compose up --detach --scale service3=1 service3
```

If we split it down:

```bash
docker compose up \
  --detach \
  --scale service3=1 \
#         ^-- overrides the scaling of the compose file
  service3
# ^-- specify which service should start
```

---

Which gives:

```bash
$ docker compose up --detach --scale service3=1 service3

[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container stackoverflow-service3-1  Started                 0.3s
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the switch was enough, but the `up` subcommand obviously needs the `service3` in there as the target.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [docker compose up command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/):

```
docker compose up service3
```

or, [docker compose start command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_start/) if the container already exist:

```
docker compose start service3
```

In case you don't want to re-create services, as workaround, you can either set the replicas also on the other services by adding to service1 and service2:

```
deploy:
  replicas: 0
```

or use the --scale option

```
docker compose up --scale service3=1 --scale service1=0 --scale service2=0
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly that doesn't meet my needs. I have `replicas: 0` as I only want to run it on demand. To use your approach I need to remove the deploy/replicas bit, and if I do that then that service would be started on every `up`.

Comment: I edited my answer to include 2 workarounds that might be useful in your case

Comment: Upvoted. I think this is a bug or undeveloped feature - depending on how you look at it - as evidenced by my link above (and others: there's discussion on this on the repo). But until it's fixed / implemented, the `--scale foo=0 --scale bar=1` workaround is reasonable, and can be scripted. At least it's a way forward. I'll leave this open for a little longer to see if there are any other approaches for the current version. Thanks again.